# How can I make the ASP.NET MVC mini profiler work with Linq 2 SQL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, mvc-mini-profiler

The [ASP.NET MVC Mini Profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) looks awesome, but I don't get the Linq 2 SQL usage example.

This is the Linq2SQL example from the profiler documentation:

```
partial class DBContext
{
   public static DBContext Get()
   {
      var conn = ProfiledDbConnection.Get(GetConnection());
      return new DBContext(conn);
      // or: return DataContextUtils.CreateDataContext<DBContext>(conn);
   }
}
```

How do I use this in my actual application? I would have expected some kind of wrapper around my DataContext, but this seems to work in a different way. I don't even know where that that "GetConnection()" method from the example is defined.

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally figured it out. In case someone else has the same question:

```
 private static DataClassesDataContext CreateNewContext()
        {
            var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(<myconnectionstring>);
            var profiledConnection = ProfiledDbConnection.Get(sqlConnection);
            return DataContextUtils.CreateDataContext<DataClassesDataContext>(profiledConnection);

        }
```

Comment: the whole point is that it is safe to use in production, there is not need to do the #if DEBUG stuff ... if a session is not profiling Get will return the original connection

Comment: i m having strange problem when using mini profiler with linq to sql plz have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410756/using-different-overload-of-datacontext-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: Where do you put this method and how are you calling it?

Comment: @RyanW: I have a wrapper class that creates my datacontext. That's where this method is located.

Comment: Do you need to do something to close this connection, or will it close itself when the context is disposed?

Comment: Where do I put this? IN my dbml? or context.cs? Do I make a new function or is there supposed to be CreteNewContext somewhere in those files? I am a bit lost with this

Comment: @ppumkin: I put this in a wrapper class around my datacontext. I needed a wrapper anyway for various other reasons.

Answer (score 6):

None of the other answers worked for me. Adding this to my DataClassesDataContext Class in my DataClasses.Designer.cs did:

```
public static DataClassesDataContext CreateNewContext()
{
     var sqlConnection = new DataClassesDataContext().Connection;
     var profiledConnection = MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnection.Get(sqlConnection);
     return new DataClassesDataContext(profiledConnection);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, there is no definition for a Get() method on ProfiledDbConnection.

Comment: @RyanW `use new ProfiledDbConnection(sqlConnection, MiniProfiler.Current)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

GetConnection() is a function that would return a DbConnection. You'll probably just do

```
var conn = ProfiledDbConnection.Get(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(your_connection_string));
```

instead.