# ASP.net mini profiler linq-to-sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, designer, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm trying to get it to record linq-to-sql in the mini profiler as [the documentation says](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/)

I add this to my `App_Code/DataClasses.designer.cs` as follows:

```
public MainContext() : 
        base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ScirraConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
{
    OnCreated();
}

// Code I'm adding in for the mini profiler
partial class DBContext
{
    public static DBContext Get()
    {
        var conn = new MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnection(GetConnection(), MiniProfiler.Current);
        return new DBContext(conn);
    }
}
```

But it throws the error:

```
The name 'GetConnection' does not exist in the current context
```

I've also tried this:

```
partial class DBContext
{
    public static DBContext Get()
    {
        var conn = ProfiledDbConnection.Get(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ScirraConnectionString"].ConnectionString));
        return new DBContext(conn);
    }
}
```

But it throws

```
'MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnection' does not contain a definition for 'Get'
```

I've refered to [How can I make the ASP.NET MVC mini profiler work with Linq 2 SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296518/how-can-i-make-the-asp-net-mvc-mini-profiler-work-with-linq-2-sql) but none of the solutions in there seem to work for me.

Can anyone show me how I would get it working for linq-to-sql?

Comment: are you using nuget or latest from source?

Comment: @sam yes I used nuget and I downloaded the binary very recently

Comment: have you tried new ProfiledDbConnection(cnn, MiniProfiler.Current) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your second experient should work if you change this:

```
ProfiledDbConnection.Get(...)
```

...to this:

```
new ProfiledDbConnection(...)
```

So instead of a static getter you should use the constructor.

I think they changed the API for ProfiledDbConnection somewhere between v1 and v2, and you can still find example code for the older version.